# Node JS app hosting with server in AWS with port 80

Tags: node.js, express

I am building a Node js app hosting platform with AWS Ubuntu.

My requirement is like this,

- App **A** running in `https://api.example.com` server IP address
  169.254.0.0/a
- App **B** running in `https://api.example2.com` IP address
  169.254.0.0/b
- APP **C** running in `https://auth.example.com` IP address
  169.254.0.0/c

So I want to run node app in the server 169.254.0.0/a (port 80).

- I run the app with node server.js command.
- My apps are express with MongoDB.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you use Docker to accomplish this goal. You can follow [this simple tutorial](https://medium.com/statuscode/dockerising-a-node-js-and-mongodb-app-d22047e2806f) or any other that you'd prefer. One beautiful advantage of docker is **isolation**. An [article](https://dzone.com/articles/top-10-benefits-of-using-docker) best explains this and I quote

> **Isolation**
>
> *Docker ensures your applications and resources are isolated and segregated. Docker makes sure each container has its own resources
>   that are isolated from other containers. You can have various
>   containers for separate applications running completely different
>   stacks. Docker helps you ensure clean app removal since each
>   application runs on its own container. If you no longer need an
>   application, you can simply delete its container. It won’t leave any
>   temporary or configuration files on your host OS.*

There are many other benefits you can [read here](https://dzone.com/articles/top-10-benefits-of-using-docker)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this 2 different ways.

1) you can open 3 separate command promps and run / monitor all 3 apps concurrently

2) you can set up crontab to fire them up

This is done by entering `crontab -e`

```
/1 * * * *  node /var/www/sites/example2.com/a/server.js
/1 * * * *  node /var/www/sites/example2.com/b/server.js
/1 * * * *  node /var/www/sites/example2.com/c/server.js
```